# program keeps having an error at "plt.plot(timelist, speedlist, 'x')"

Tags: python

I am trying to plot the points on the graph, but the program keeps having an error at "plt.plot(timelist, speedlist, 'x')". I needed help to understand why I cannot use the lists timelist and speedlist.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
timelist = []
speedlist = []

table = pd.read_csv('C:MLK+Bailey+Central/2019-01-20.csv')
table1 = pd.read_csv('C:MLK+Bailey+Central/2019-01-21.csv')
table2 = pd.read_csv('C:MLK+Bailey+Central/2019-01-22.csv')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 10))



time = table['timestamp']
time1 = table1['timestamp']
time2 = table2['timestamp']

speed = table['speed_mph']
speed1 = table1['speed_mph']
speed2 = table2['speed_mph']

timelist.append(time)
timelist.append(time1)
timelist.append(time2)

speedlist.append(speed)
speedlist.append(speed1)
speedlist.append(speed2)



plt.plot(timelist, speedlist, 'x')
plt.xlabel('Time (hrs)')
plt.ylabel('Speed (mph)')
plt.title('Speed versus Time Line Graph')
plt.show()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-f1352f91eb11> in <module>
     30 
     31 
---> 32 plt.plot(timelist, speedlist, 'x')
     33 plt.xlabel('Time (hrs)')
     34 plt.ylabel('Speed (mph)')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2809     return gca().plot(
   2810         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley, **({"data": data} if data
-> 2811         is not None else {}), **kwargs)
```

Lists: [0         0:00
1         0:00
2         0:00
3         0:00
4         0:00
5         0:00
6         0:00
7         0:00
8         0:00
9         0:00
10        0:00
11        0:00
12        0:00
13        0:00
14        0:00
15        0:00
16        0:00
17        0:00
18        0:00
19        0:00
20        0:00
21        0:00
22        0:00
23        0:00
24        0:00
25        0:00
26        0:01
27        0:01
28        0:01
29        0:01
         ...
24056    23:56
24057    23:56
24058    23:56
24059    23:56
24060    23:57
24061    23:57
24062    23:57
24063    23:57
24064    23:57
24065    23:57
24066    23:57
24067    23:57
24068    23:57
24069    23:57
24070    23:58
24071    23:58
24072    23:58
24073    23:58
24074    23:58
24075    23:58
24076    23:58
24077    23:58
24078    23:58
24079    23:58
24080    23:59
24081    23:59
24082    23:59
24083    23:59
24084    23:59
24085    23:59
Name: timestamp, Length: 24086, dtype: object, 0        00:00

```
1        00:01
2        00:05
3        00:05
4        00:11
5        00:15
6        00:20
7        00:21
8        00:26
9        00:27
10       00:30
11       00:33
12       00:35
13       00:41
14       00:43
15       00:44
16       00:44
17       01:00
18       01:03
19       01:05
20       01:06
21       01:12
22       01:33
23       01:34
24       01:40
25       01:48
26       02:10
27       02:13
28       02:19
29       02:22
         ...  
32104    23:12
32105    23:12
32106    23:12
32107    23:13
32108    23:14
32109    23:15
32110    23:19
32111    23:19
32112    23:21
32113    23:22
32114    23:27
32115    23:28
32116    23:29
32117    23:29
32118    23:31
32119    23:33
32120    23:34
32121    23:34
32122    23:36
32123    23:36
32124    23:37
32125    23:41
32126    23:43
32127    23:46
32128    23:51
32129    23:54
32130    23:57
32131    23:57
32132    23:58
32133    23:59
Name: timestamp, Length: 32134, dtype: object, 0        00:02
1        00:05
2        00:10
3        00:19
4        00:28
5        00:28
6        00:45
7        00:47
8        00:48
9        00:49
10       00:55
11       01:02
12       01:08
13       01:22
14       01:28
15       01:37
16       01:38
17       01:39
18       01:49
19       01:57
20       02:09
21       02:39
22       03:03
23       03:18
24       03:43
25       03:48
26       04:03
27       04:08
28       04:24
29       04:41
         ...  
44858    23:23
44859    23:25
44860    23:27
44861    23:28
44862    23:28
44863    23:28
44864    23:29
44865    23:30
44866    23:32
44867    23:39
44868    23:39
44869    23:40
44870    23:41
44871    23:43
44872    23:45
44873    23:46
44874    23:46
44875    23:48
44876    23:49
44877    23:51
44878    23:52
44879    23:54
44880    23:54
44881    23:56
44882    23:56
44883    23:56
44884    23:57
44885    23:58
44886    23:58
44887    23:58
Name: timestamp, Length: 44888, dtype: object] [0         8
1         5
2         7
3         9
4         3
5        15
6        11
7        14
8        18
9        25
10        9
11        0
12       12
13        8
14        5
15        7
16        9
17        3
18       15
19       11
20       14
21       18
22       25
23        9
24        0
25       12
26        0
27        6
28       23
29       14
         ..
24056    19
24057    21
24058    11
24059     9
24060     6
24061     9
24062     9
24063     4
24064    22
24065     6
24066     9
24067     9
24068     4
24069    22
24070    17
24071     8
24072    17
24073    12
24074    37
24075    17
24076     8
24077    17
24078    12
24079    37
24080    29
24081    14
24082    20
24083    29
24084    14
24085    20
Name: speed_mph, Length: 24086, dtype: int64, 0         0
1        16
2        13
3         6
4         0
5         0
6        15
7         0
8         0
9        17
10        0
11       17
12       15
13       15
14       14
15        0
16       16
17       13
18        9
19        5
20       16
21        8
22       11
23        6
24       13
25       15
26        0
27        8
28       18
29       16
         ..
32104    18
32105    24
32106    26
32107    10
32108     6
32109    29
32110    12
32111    34
32112    11
32113    10
32114     6
32115    12
32116     4
32117     9
32118    11
32119    11
32120    26
32121    32
32122    16
32123    13
32124     7
32125    10
32126     7
32127    22
32128    10
32129    11
32130     9
32131    34
32132     6
32133    28
Name: speed_mph, Length: 32134, dtype: int64, 0         0
1         8
2         5
3        15
4         0
5         7
6         4
7         8
8        14
9         0
10        8
11        0
12        4
13        7
14        0
15       13
16       16
17       15
18       18
19       14
20        0
21       11
22       41
23       21
24       15
25       10
26        6
27        9
28        0
29       16
         ..
44858    37
44859    13
44860    10
44861    10
44862    15
44863    13
44864    34
44865    35
44866    34
44867    10
44868    31
44869    11
44870    11
44871    11
44872    25
44873    13
44874    19
44875    15
44876    35
44877    12
44878    26
44879    11
44880    16
44881    17
44882    10
44883    22
44884    15
44885    12
44886     8
44887    11
```

Comment: try checking the size of both array and even look is there any nan?

Comment: Add `print(speedlist, timelist)` **before** `plt.plot(timelist, speedlist, 'x')`, and update the question with that info (or paste it in a comment).

Comment: The program printed the list out and then returned the same message.

Comment: I know that, but I asked you to provide the lists.

Comment: I added the list

Comment: Hmm, not a *pandas* expert :(. Could you also add `print(type(timelist[0]), type(timelist[0][0])`?

Comment: That prints out <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Also for `type(timelist[0][0])` (notice 2 `[0]`s)? Could you add more `[0]`s until it prints smth else?

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.plot(timelist, speedlist)
```

try this .

```
import matplotlib.dates as md
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'toronto_time': ['00:50',
                                    '01:55',
                                    '02:18',
                                    '05:24',
                                    '05:34',
                                    '06:33'],
                    'description': ['STATS', 'STATS', 'DEV_OL', 'STATS', 'STATS', 
                                    'CMD_ERROR']})
df['toronto_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['toronto_time'], format='%H:%M')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

plt.plot('toronto_time', 'description', data=df)
ax.set_xlim(df['toronto_time'].min()-pd.Timedelta(1,'h'),
            df['toronto_time'].max()+pd.Timedelta(1,'h'))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval = 1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))



plt.show()
```

you can still learn from this to manage time.

Comment: Nothing happened

Comment: remove : from the list , i can see many. how can machine plot ' : '?

Comment: ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))